# Displaying two sets of results - UNION not quite working

Tags: mysql

I'm a complete newbie to MySQL and am trying to retrieve two sets of results to display on the same page, one on top of the other. I've managed to get the below working with the UNION function and it 'almost' does what I need except it combines the results in ONE table. I want the second of these SELECT commands to display as a distinct table below the first. Is that possible. Here's my code so far:

```
    SELECT wp_wpdatatable_1.season,
   wp_wpdatatable_1.date,
   wp_wpdatatable_1.ha,
   wp_wpdatatable_1.competition,
   wp_wpdatatable_1.result,
   wp_wpdatatable_1.score,
   wp_wpdatatable_1.scorers
   FROM wp_wpdatatable_1
   WHERE 1=1 
   AND wp_wpdatatable_1.opponents = 'Everton'

   UNION 

    SELECT
    null AS count1,
    null AS count2,
    null AS count3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN opponents='Everton' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS played,
    SUM(CASE WHEN result LIKE 'W' and opponents='Everton' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS won,
    SUM(CASE WHEN result LIKE 'D' and opponents='Everton' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS drawn,
    SUM(CASE WHEN result LIKE 'L' and opponents='Everton' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS lost
    FROM wp_wpdatatable_1
```

Comment: Against Everton, wouldn't it always be 'W'?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to see 2 separate column headers, in which case not sure this is possible in mySQL?

But if you just mean you want the order of rows one after the other, add a dummy column which you can order by (and not essential for below as the order by will make the records unique, but good practice in your use case, add a UNION ALL to avoid elimination of duplicate rows per docs http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html )

`(SELECT wp_wpdatatable_1.season,
   wp_wpdatatable_1.date,
   wp_wpdatatable_1.ha,
   wp_wpdatatable_1.competition,
   wp_wpdatatable_1.result,
   wp_wpdatatable_1.score,
   wp_wpdatatable_1.scorers,
   1 as table_order
   FROM wp_wpdatatable_1
   WHERE 1=1 
   AND wp_wpdatatable_1.opponents = 'Everton'
)
   UNION ALL
(
    SELECT
    null AS count1,
    null AS count2,
    null AS count3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN opponents='Everton' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS played,
    SUM(CASE WHEN result LIKE 'W' and opponents='Everton' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS won,
    SUM(CASE WHEN result LIKE 'D' and opponents='Everton' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS drawn,
    SUM(CASE WHEN result LIKE 'L' and opponents='Everton' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS lost,
    2 as table_order
    FROM wp_wpdatatable_1
)
ORDER BY table_order`